# SQL Server fetch data php

Tags: php, sql-server, php-mssql

I want to pull the data in the database by connecting to SQL Server. I can connect to SQL Server but I can't print the data. I get blank screen output. What is the problem?

```
<?php
$myServer = "...";
$myUser = "...";
$myPass = "....";
$myDB = "...";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT form_adres, form_sehir, form_adsoyad";
$query .= "FROM databasename.omg_user.ie_form";
$query .= "WHERE form_no='15275'";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["form_adres"] . $row["form_sehir"] . $row["form_adsoyad"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Change your query to `$query = "SELECT 1 AS [TEST]"` to ensure there is nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: Empty output is coming @Zhorov

Comment: Yes the data is returning @Zhorov

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme Check the table name - `databasename.omg_user.ie_form`. Is it possible to have this table in different databases or/and with different schema?

Comment: "databasename.username.tablename" Is the way of writing correct?

Comment: @SH It should be `database.schema.table`, In most cases `database.dbo.table`. If you use `mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)` to connect to `database`, your statement should be `SELECT .. FROM schema.table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the generated T-SQL Statment - missing spaces before `FROM` and `WHERE`. The generated statement is `SELECT form_adres, form_sehir, form_adsoyadFROM databasename.omg_user.ie_formWHERE form_no='15275'`. Fix the statement and always check the result from `mssql_query()` execution:

```
<?php
...

// declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = " SELECT form_adres, form_sehir, form_adsoyad";
$query .= " FROM databasename.omg_user.ie_form";
$query .= " WHERE form_no='15275'";

// execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query, $dbhandle);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "Error (mssql_query): ".mssql_get_last_message();
    exit;
}   

...
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting a blank screen again. It doesn't print the error either

Comment: No it doesn't turn

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme I'm able to reproduce this in my test environment and if you have data, that matches your `WHERE` clause, adding spaces before `FROM` and `WHERE` will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code..

```
//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT form_adres, form_sehir, form_adsoyad";
$query .= "FROM databasename.omg_user.ie_form";
$query .= "WHERE form_no='15275'";
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query($dbhandle, $query);
```

Comment: There is a blank page again

Comment: You can use this   //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT form_adres, form_sehir, form_adsoyad from table_name where form_no='15275'";
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query($dbhandle, $query);

Comment: OP is using SQL server, not MySQL. Anyway, this query has syntax errors and would not work.